# Is the new 'showon' attribute only for back-end forms?

Tags: joomla-3.x, form, fields

I tried using the showon form field attribute in a front-end form with no working results.

Not even the example given here is working: https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field#Showon

Is there anything missing, do I have to include a certain script manually when I wanna use it in the front-end?

I'm using joomla 3.4.1, front end is a T3 template, in case that matters.

Any ideas or solutions ?

EDIT:
The form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset name="main">  
        <field name="foo" type="list"  >
            <option value="1">JYES</option>
            <option value="0">JNO</option>
        </field>

        <field name="bar" type="text" showon="foo:1" />

        <field name="foo2" type="text"  />

        <field name="bar2" type="text" showon="foo2:1" />
    </fieldset>  
</form>
```

The template

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');

?>

<form action="...>"
      method="post" 
    onsubmit="return false;" 
    name="adminForm" id="adminForm" class="form-validate">
    <div class="form-horizontal adminform">
        <fieldset class="">
            <legend><?php echo 'test'; ?></legend>
                <div class="span6">
                    <?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset() as $field): ?>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $field->label; ?></div>
                            <div class="controls"><?php echo $field->input; ?></div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
</form>
```

EDIT 2:Found a solution in joomla core files

if the template code above is updated from:

```
<div class="span6">
    <?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset() as $field): ?>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $field->label; ?></div>
            <div class="controls"><?php echo $field->input; ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="span6">
    <?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset() as $field): ?>
        <?php
        $class = '';
        $rel = '';
        if ($showon = $field->getAttribute('showon')) {
            JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
            JHtml::_('script', 'jui/cms.js', false, true);
            $id = $this->form->getFormControl();
            $showon = explode(':', $showon, 2);
            $class = ' showon_' . implode(' showon_', explode(',', $showon[1]));
            $rel = ' rel="showon_' . $id . '[' . $showon[0] . ']"';
        }
        ?>
        <div class="control-group<?php echo $class; ?>"<?php echo $rel; ?>>
            <div class="control-label"><?php echo $field->label; ?></div>
            <div class="controls"><?php echo $field->input; ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

it works

SO am I supposed to manually add this part all the time?

Docu doesn't state anything about this, I need to load the cms.js file manually and build the control-grouptag myself? Seems strange

Comment: Can you please show the code you're using?

Comment: I added the form and the tmpl code

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's a problem related to system core, Your template/Joomla don't load JS for that functionality, just add JS `/media/jui/js/cms.js` in your controller where you load form.

regards

Comment: Adding just the script does not work, I also have to actually add the code to create the correct parent control-group div as my EDIT 2 shows. Neither action is described in the docu.

Answer (score 2):

It should work as long as your form is generated using JForm.
If you build your HTML for the form yourself, then you may have to manually add the needed code and markup.
Try rendering the field using `<?php echo $this->form->renderField('title'); ?>` or in case of the foreach you could use `<?php echo $this->form->renderField($field->fieldname); ?>`
This seems to work in my case.

Comment: I'll give it a try as son as I get some time. I do generate the form the 'standard' way as shown in most tutorials. And I'm sure I used it once before, to try it out and had no need for those hoops. I suspect (really only guessing at this point) it has to do with the updates. This Joomla was a 3.0 once  and has been updated over time to 3.4

Comment: Updates shouldn't make a difference. However using JForm to generate the form does make a difference.